# ¿Cómo esperar un valor asíncrono dentro de un ciclo for?

Tags: javascript, promesas, asincronismo

Quiero hacer que un ciclo for espere por un `setTimeout` antes de seguir con la siguiente interacción. Traté esto pero no funciona.

```js
async function loadNotes(request) {

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let saludo;
    setTimeout(function() {
      saludo = "hola";
    }, 2000)

    console.log(await saludo);

    console.log(i)
  }
}
loadNotes();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para eso solo tienes que colocar tu código dentro de una promesa.

```js
async function loadNotes(request){

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    
    const texto = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      setTimeout(function() {
          resolve("hola");
      }, 2000);
    });

    console.log(texto, i);
  }
}

loadNotes();
```

Comment: estupendo! gracias